# Xamarin Forms ListView ScrollTo an empty group

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to scroll to a specified *group* in a **ListView**, but it won't let me. The `ScrollTo` function will only scroll to an item within a specific group. I would be fine doing that except some of my groups don't have any items.

I'm trying to do the following call but it doesn't work if the group at that index has an empty list:

```
ListView.ScrollTo(groupList[index].FirstOrDefault(), groupList[index], ScrollToPosition.MakeVisible, false)
```

Is there maybe another way that I can scroll to that specified group?

Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite follow you.Could you please explain this question in details?

Comment: If you enable grouping on the listview, it allows you to label or name each section of items. For instance, in a contact book app, you might have headers like a,b,c, etc. and under each group you would have people who's names start with that given letter. You can see this more specifically here: https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-listview-grouping/

If you wanted to have an a-z off to the side where the scroll bar normally is to jump to a specific group, you can use the scrollTo method to jump to that section. However, the scrollTo function doesn't work if the group is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,it is just the case as you said.

And from the official document [ScrollTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listview.scrollto?view=xamarin-forms), we could find that we need to specify a specific Item to jump to that place.

[image]

Yes, I also think this is unreasonable. If the Item is empty, it should jump to the corresponding Group header.And I have commit a feature request in official document, you can follow it [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8279).

We are really sorry for the inconvenience. And we will urge the development team to solve this problem as soon as possible. Please wait patiently.